# Why is my TextInput losing focus every time I enter a character?

Tags: react-native

I have a component with a `TextInput` linked to the state, based on the ReactNative documentation:

```
function NewItemView(): JSX.Element {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const submitText = () => {
        dispatch(createRecord(text))
        setText("")
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#eeeeff',
                    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                }}
                onChangeText={setText}
                value={text}
            />
            <Button
                title='Create new record'
                onPress={submitText}
            />
        </View>
    )

}
```

On the iPhone Simulator, whenever I enter a character in the text input, the field loses focus, and I have to tap into it again to enter another character.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I have the field maintain focus while I type multiple characters?

**edit:** for context, this is how the view is being used:

```
function TodoList(): JSX.Element {

    const state: State = useSelector((state: any) => state.list);

actions
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchList)
    }, [])

    return (<View>
        <NewItemView/>
        <FlatList 
            data={state.data}
            renderItem={({item}) => <ItemCell text={item.text} />}
        />
    </View>)
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine, what else is on the screen? Any useEffects running?

Comment: There is a useEffects running on the parent view, but it's being called with an empty dependency array so if I understand correctly it should only execute once when the view loads

Comment: Can you paste the code of the screen where you're using the component?

Comment: I faced this issue when typing in iphone too, I solved the issue by adding `defaultValue={text}` to TextInput props.

Comment: @Abe I have added the context of the parent to this component

Comment: @kiuQ I have added the defaultValue but it did not help